# Multiple variable formatting at one time on VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a js file which contains around 200 enums with names like -

```
abc
def
ghi
...
```

I want all these enums to be in uppercase rather than writing it again as it can cause typos.

Tried text.toUpperCase() but it will still give me only one output on vs code

Comment: are these enums referenced anywhere outside of this file? do you want to rename instances outside of this file? please actually show context. what is the text preceding and following the names of these enum declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select all your enum keys that you wish to uppercase using **ctrl+d**
2. Then press **ctrl+shift+p** and type uppercase
3. Press **Enter**

[image: vs code dropdown]

Comment: Thnks! This is exactly what I needed

Comment: please avoid answering duplicates. read [/help/how-to-answer](/help/how-to-answer)